# Multiple custom views in Scroll view Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-custom-view

I created custom view and want to insert multiple numbers of it to the Scroll list, but always only one view is displayed:

```
  <ScrollView 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/buttonsPart"
  android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
  android:background="@drawable/greylayer">

  <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <com.test.app.canvas.MatchCanvas
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="400px"/>

      <com.test.app.canvas.MatchCanvas
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="400px"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

I believe its easily possible to insert as many custom views to ScrollView, but somehow I still have only 1 instance of MatchCanvas. What should I do?

Comment: Not the problem, but as an FYI, you don't want to use `px`, use `dp` (density independent pixels) instead.

Comment: @dmon Can I ask a few question in chat about android multiple screen size support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default LinearLayout is horizontal, so add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the LinearLayout to resolve the issue.